# How to restore BIOS configuration access on Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, uefi, bios

I can no longer access the BIOS on my PC. I don't know what caused it, but it must have happened since I installed Arch Linux (my only OS) with UEFI GRUB. I have accessed the BIOS dozens of times before, but none of the standard methods work anymore. From the manual:

> To enter BIOS Setup at startup:
>
> Press [Delete] or [F2] during the Power-On Self Test (POST).

I've tried these and heaps of other keys, including ESC, F1 through F3, and F8 through F12. I've tried holding them or pressing repeatedly. I've also tried `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`, but no go. I also tried running `fwsetup` in the GRUB console, but it just rebooted. During reboot I either see nothing at all before the GRUB menu or just a quick flash of a POST status screen without any keyboard prompt.

Some requested information:

```
$ sudo dmidecode -s system-manufacturer
System manufacturer
$ sudo dmidecode -s system-product-name
System Product Name
$ sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-manufacturer
ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC.
$ sudo dmidecode -s baseboard-product-name
TUF B360-PRO GAMING (WI-FI)
$ sudo dmidecode -s bios-vendor
American Megatrends Inc.
$ efibootmgr -v
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 10 seconds
BootOrder: 0001
Boot0001* GRUB  HD(1,GPT,fa065366-79e7-40d2-9eab-70dc8e98bfb1,0x800,0xff800)/File(\EFI\GRUB\grubx64.efi)
```

(I just bumped the timeout with `efibootmgr` earlier, but it doesn't seem to have had any appreciable effect.)

I'm not sure even `fwupdmgr` recognises the BIOS - it shows some AMI hardware, but doesn't explicitly call any of it out as a BIOS/UEFI device:

```
$ sudo fwupdmgr get-devices
[…]
├─System Firmware:
│ │   Device ID:          c4e002c2199cf4d6bd3e13eee33cf3b821d95914
│ │   Current version:    4610
│ │   Minimum Version:    4610
│ │   Vendor:             System manufacturer (DMI:American Megatrends Inc.)
│ │   Update Error:       Cannot install update when system battery is not at least 10%
│ │   GUIDs:              f9fabfb9-6756-506b-a7c4-2d690177282b
│ │                       230c8b18-8d9b-53ec-838b-6cfc0383493a ← main-system-firmware
│ │                       1fedd657-6193-5ae8-b10f-e921c108ce73 ← UEFI\RES_{F9FABFB9-6756-506B-A7C4-2D690177282B}
│ │   Device Flags:       • Internal device
│ │                       • System requires external power source
│ │                       • Needs a reboot after installation
│ │                       • Cryptographic hash verification is available
│ │                       • Device is usable for the duration of the update
│ │                       • Updatable
│ │ 
│ └─UEFI dbx:
│       Device ID:        362301da643102b9f38477387e2193e57abaa590
│       Summary:          UEFI Revocation Database
│       Current version:  238
│       Minimum Version:  238
│       Vendor:           UEFI:Linux Foundation
│       Install Duration: 1 second
│       GUIDs:            fda6234b-adcb-5105-8515-9af647d29775 ← UEFI\CRT_D7F66BE77CEF858C174BF4338A99263C8795B74E02026411F5F532F716AE3263
│                         f8ff0d50-c757-5dc3-951a-39d86e16f419 ← UEFI\CRT_D7F66BE77CEF858C174BF4338A99263C8795B74E02026411F5F532F716AE3263&ARCH_X64
│                         c6682ade-b5ec-57c4-b687-676351208742 ← UEFI\CRT_A1117F516A32CEFCBA3F2D1ACE10A87972FD6BBE8FE0D0B996E09E65D802A503
│                         f8ba2887-9411-5c36-9cee-88995bb39731 ← UEFI\CRT_A1117F516A32CEFCBA3F2D1ACE10A87972FD6BBE8FE0D0B996E09E65D802A503&ARCH_X64
│                         7d5759e5-9aa0-5f0c-abd6-7439bb11b9f6 ← UEFI\CRT_ED1FE72CB9CA31C9AF5B757AFCD733323D675825032E6CED7FE1AE9EB767998C
│                         0c7691e1-b6f2-5d71-bc9c-aabee364c916 ← UEFI\CRT_ED1FE72CB9CA31C9AF5B757AFCD733323D675825032E6CED7FE1AE9EB767998C&ARCH_X64
│       Device Flags:     • Internal device
│                         • Updatable
│                         • Needs a reboot after installation
│     
[…]
$ sudo fwupdmgr update
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • USB3.0 Hub
 • BCM920702 Bluetooth 4.0
 • UEFI dbx
 • USB2.0 Hub
Devices with the latest available firmware version:
 • Unifying Receiver
```

Note: the motherboard [general info link](https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/All-series/TUF-B360-PRO-GAMING-WI-FI/), [manual in PDF](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA1151/TUF_B360-PRO_GAMING_WI-FI/E13811_TUF_B360-PRO_GAMING_WI-FI_UM_WEB.pdf).

Comment: I decided to convert answer to comment, so is Clearing CMOS = resetting BIOS on your options list? if so, I would go for it.

Comment: I hope I can avoid it, if it has a non-zero chance of interfering with UEFI functionality.

Comment: According to https://www.asus.com/Motherboards-Components/Motherboards/TUF-Gaming/TUF-B360-PRO-GAMING-WI-FI/HelpDesk_BIOS/ the latest "BIOS" (actually UEFI system firmware) is version 2701, released 2021-04-16. The fact that `fwupdmgr get-devices` reports the current version of "system firmware" as 4610 is kind of strange. Also the "Update error" seems to refer to system battery level check, which is a thing on laptop firmware updates...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resetting the BIOS to re-enable access.